# Send or execute internet direction without downloading annything

Tags: c++, url, terminal, send, playback

I have a wireless IP cam that play sounds. I know how to play this sounds because i know the direction and the command. I tried it with this Terminal command: `http://192.168.0.90/axis-cgi/playclip.cgi?clip=6`

The problem is wget command download the clip and i only want to reproduce it. Beacuse i want to do into a program.

Any option to do it in terminal. Or directly from a C++ program.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That didnt make much sense to me. "direction"? what does direction have to do with this? so, you have a web cam that plays sounds, Im guessing from windows you typed the URL and it played the sound in media player? wget does exactly that, it goes and gets the file you pointed at, no more. If you want it to "play" it you would then need to do something from the command line to say so. What sort of "terminal" are you using?

Comment: @BugFinder: He is spanish and maybe used "direction" instead of (URL) "address".

Comment: yeah, sorry is URL address. I use terminal or a C++ command.

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly, but if you want a wget-like HTTP client to use in your program, you could take a look at [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). Its frontend program `curl` behaves very similarly to `wget`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mplayer` or `vlc` will stream the URL and play it as if it was a local file. As for doing it in C++, you have much more work to do (find an HTTP library, read the contents, decode it and reproduce it. Maybe the `ffmpeg` library can help you here.

Comment: Sorry but i don't want to do a URL stream. Only want to send the URL direction to play a sound.

Comment: Jorge, you either stream it or download *and* then play it. There is no other way.